# Ubuntu 12.04 + PHP 5.6 + Memcached = How to resolve dependencies?

Tags: php, ubuntu, memcached, ubuntu-12.04

simple question.

I'm trying to install php + memcached on ubuntu.

First, i do this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6 # Good
$ sudo apt-get update                         # Good
$ sudo apt-get upgrade -y                     # Good
$ sudo apt-get install php5 -y                # Good
$ sudo apt-get install php5-fpm -y            # Good
```

But then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-memcached -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-memcached : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.29-1~dotdeb.0) but 5.6.9+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Some info about server:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release | grep PRETTY
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)"

$ php -v | grep PHP
PHP 5.6.9-1+deb.sury.org~precise+2 (cli) (built: May 26 2015 15:13:29)

$ php5-fpm -v | grep PHP
PHP 5.6.9-1+deb.sury.org~precise+2 (fpm-fcgi) (built: May 26 2015 15:38:14)

$ apt-cache policy php5-common
php5-common:
  Installed: 5.6.9+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+2
```

How can i resolve this and install memcached extension on 5.6?

I'm also try to install from PECL, but

```
$ pecl install memcache
pecl/memcache is already installed and is the same as the released version 2.2.7
install failed
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved for myself this problem with Ondřej Surý repo and aptitude.
I have php 5.5.9 (Ubuntu 14.04). It was message

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    php5-memcached : Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.29-1~dotdeb.0) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.9 is to be installed

I added Ondrej repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
```

And then install php5-memcache and php5-memcached by:

```
sudo aptitude install php5-memcached
```

and press "n" several times, when aptitude offered old php version. After about 5 times aptitude said:

```
Next actions will solved depends:

 Install next packets:             
1)     php5-memcached [2.1.0-6build1 (trusty)]
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

And press Y.